# “To the next time” vs. “Till the next time”

Tags: prepositions, expression-choice

Could you tell me which form is correct, and why?

- to the next time, name
- till the next time, name

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide some context; what exact meaning are you trying to express? What do you think is the correct form when written in a full sentence? Why do you think one form or the other is incorrect, and what research have you attempted thus far into the matter? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 3):

Below, I use [] for implied words, {} for optional words:

> [Yours] till the next time [we meet or correspond],
>
> Name

The only place that the phrasing *to . . . next time* would work is in a closing such as this:

> Looking forward to {the} next time [we meet or correspond],
>
> Name

Oh by the way, don’t let anybody convince you that you need to write *until*—or worse yet, *’til*—because *till* is just fine.

Comment: Why is "till" fine?  I've always written "'til" - is this form incorrect? Or, has it just faded into obscurity?

Comment: @Oldbag: the usage "'til" comes from the mistaken understanding of 'til being the appropriate shortening of "until".  Actually, "till" came first, and was later supplanted by "until". So you could say 'til is a back-formation where none is needed, as the original form still exists. I'm not saying it's wrong to use 'til; I'm just saying it's wrong to insist that 'til is preferable to till, or especially to insist that till is wrong.